# Why is this while loop not giving me any output?

Tags: list-manipulation, recursion, infinite-loop

I have following code in my Mathematica:

```
P[k_?NumericQ, L_?NumericQ] := P[k, L] = NIntegrate[Exp[I*k*r]*1/r^(2/3), {r, 0, L}];

i = 1;

rhot = {};

a[k_] := RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, Sqrt[Re[P[k, 100]]]]] + 
   I*RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, Sqrt[Im[P[k, 100]]]]];

While[i < 3, 
      alist = Table[a[k], {k, 2*Pi/100, 2*Pi, 2*Pi/100}]; 
      rslist = Fourier[alist]; 
      rhotl = Total[rslist];
      Append[rhot, rhot1]; 
      i++]
```

Unfortunately, the while loop does not give any output. Any idea why this is so?

Comment: Try with `Table` or `AppendTo`.

Comment: You mean change the statement  Append[rhot, rhot1];  to  AppendTo[rhot, rhot1]; ?

Comment: `rhot = Append[rhot, Total[rslist]];`
`Append[]` doesn't actually dynamically change a list, you still need `=`. With `AppendTo` you don't need `=`